# Password-protect a web service (flask-based) without changing it's code

Tags: networking, security, python, webserver

I'm using beancount's 3rd-party web UI, fava. Basically that means I run a web service on a certain port. There is no authentication or security for that web service. In case it's important, fava uses python and flask.

I want to access this web service over the internet, and port forwarding the appropriate port on my router allows me to do this easily. However anyone else who knows the port would be able to access this service (i.e. my only security is obscurity from a high port number).

How can I password protect the service, at the minimum? Even better, could I limit access to the service to certain devices (not IP addresses), such as my own smartphone (and my wife's)?

I've considered using ssh tunneling on our phones, but that would probably be too complex/troublesome for my wife to use. Ideally I'd like her to be able to just click on a bookmark in her browser to access the website (perhaps with a password check along the way), rather than having to load up connectbot and click connect.

Answer (score 2):

I also needed to apply minimal protection to fava.  What I did was to serve fava over [FastCGI](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/fastcgi/) instead of its built-in http server.  Here's a very minimal wrapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def main():
    try:
        # In case you're running Python 2.x:  (untested with fava)
        from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
    except ImportError:
        # For Python 3.x:
        from flipflop import WSGIServer

    from fava.application import app, load_file

    app.config['BEANCOUNT_FILES'] = ['/path/to/your/ledger.beancount',]
    load_file()
    WSGIServer(app).run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys as _sys
    _sys.exit(main())
```

You'll of course need flipflop for Python 3.x, or flup for Python 2.x.

To get Apache to load this, you have many options.  Here's 2:

1. Save the file as "fava.fcgi", make it executable by Apache's user ID, and configure Apache to serve .fcgi files.  I didn't do this, because I don't like the .fcgi extension being present in my urls, and I didn't want to bother with (IMHO) cumbersome rewrite rules.
2. My simpler approach:  Save the file as "fava", make it executable by Apache, and add these lines to a .htaccess for other server config file:

   ```
   <Files fava>
       # Use this with Debian package libapache2-mod-fastcgi
       SetHandler fastcgi-script
       # Or this with Debian package libapache2-mod-fcgid
       #SetHandler fcgid-script
   </Files>
   ```

You may need to run `a2enmod fastcgi` or `a2enmod fcgid` depending on which Apache FastCGI module you decide to use.

And most importantly, set some sort of password mechanism, and you probably want to require SSL.  For example:  (There may be a more elegant way to combine this `Directory` section with the above `Files` section...)

```
# Set this to whatever directory contains fava:
<Directory /path/to/dir/containing/fava/>
    Options +ExecCGI
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLRequireSSL
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Mr. Coffee"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpasswd.whatever
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Final notes:  Instead of FastCGI, other mechanisms may work as well, such as [WSGI](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/), but you will need to change (or simplify?) my wrapper script.